# R : issue in installation of Shiny package

Tags: r, shiny, installation-package

I am using R studio 0.97 along with R version 3.1.2. I keep getting the following issue:

> Warning in install.packages: 
>   unable to move temporary installation '...\My Documents\R\win-library\3.1\file14984b915ea3\shiny' to '...\My Documents\R\win-library\3.1\shiny'

I have already tried installing Shiny package with same version R in another system and it installed perfectly.

Any specific thing that I should know of? Please suggest any fix for this.

Comment: Do you have the rights to write into this directory? "Admin rights" on Windows? Can you install other packages?

Comment: I do not have admin rights but I can right in that directory. I have even installed other packages and they are in the same folder.